# Dualboot (Ubuntu 15.10, Win 10) hibernating issue (Ubuntu->hibernate->win->Ubuntu)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows, 15.10, hibernate

I recently decided to dualboot my Win 10 Laptop (Legacy BIOS).
At first i used Linux Mint however i changed to Ubuntu 15.04 (and upgraded to 15.10 afterwards) because of several issues, Ubuntu solved all of them.

**Fast boot in Windows is disabled.**

Today I decided to try out hibernating. Here is what *works*:

- Hibernating Win 10, using Ubuntu, reboot/hibernate that and get back into Win 10
- Hibernating Ubuntu and rebooting into Ubuntu or Win 10(hibernated or not)

What doesn't work however is hibernating Ubuntu, booting into Win 10, hibernating and *then* trying to get back into Ubuntu.
What happens is that it displays 'ACPI more than one lid device found' and does some fsck-magic on the inodes (/dev/sda6, ext6, Ubuntu's partition), afterwards I get a black screen. REISUB doesn't help (except the reboot part, sometimes), neither does <kbd>CTRL+ALT+F1</kbd>.
After creating the file following this guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/power-hibernate.html instead of a black screen I got to the login screen. One time i could login, open console and everything froze, the other time it froze right after i could see the login screen. And again, nothing helped(REISUB, <kbd>CTRL+ALT+F1</kbd>).

I figured that this particular thing just does not work in my case so I just had to be careful to always reboot into Ubuntu after hibernating it.
So then I wanted to reinstall grub-customizer and configure Ubuntu as first in grub. Then shit started to go down: while installing I got several errors that the directories are write-protected etc. so I rebooted. Fsck again, but it failed and i had to do a manual fsck on /dev/sda6, reboot again, fsck doing some stuff on the inodes as described before, luckily i got back into Ubuntu just fine (thank you fsck) and my filesystem seems to work normal again.

While i could go fine with being careful not to boot into Windows after hibernating Ubuntu, this does pose a certain risk. I also have no clue as to why this happens, Windows shouldn't mess with an ext6 partition afaik.

Does anybody have an idea why this happens, or how to solve it?
If you need any additional information, I'll be happy to provide it.

Comment: While you have taken much effort to document this behavior I think this should better be reported as a bug on the bug tracker. I'm not sure but I think it is a hardware issue (a similar report on kernel.org: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=16512), so more details about your hardware are needed and I have some doubt that this can be resolved quickly. I'm not a firmware engineer nor a kernel hacker, but from what I read hibernation on Linux is risky and even more so if you hibernate several OS on the same machine (or do firmware upgrades). Is it possible for you try it with UEFI?

Comment: If there is a way to somehow migrate my windows and Linux from Legacy BIOS to UEFI I could try that. However I find it weird that hibernating works just fine as long as I don't go into windows, especially considering that it produces errors in my Linux file system that windows does not even tamper with. It's even weirder that adding this file as described in the guide replaces a black screen with the login screen when this error happens. I have no clue how a hardware issue can cause such behaviour.

Comment: I recently migrated my Windows 10 Insider VM from MBR to GPT by attaching another drive, booting into Ubuntu, creating a new GPT table on the new drive and just copying the partitions. After that was done I reinstalled the bootloader (you would need to do that for both, there is `bcdboot` on the install media for Windows and [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/88432/40581) for Grub with package grub-efi-amd64-bin) in UEFI, given that your machine supports UEFI of course. If you have a spare drive this would be a low risk solution to try.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a spare drive and I can't connect a second one to my laptop, so I'd have to buy one and somehow connect it via USB, so I think I won't try that out. Well, maybe an update will solve it or someone on here shows up with a solution, I think I'll be going with suspend and only carefully hibernating so I won't start windows when Ubuntu is hibernated. I'm happy enough that windows can hibernate without issues, it's takes too damn long until I can use it otherwise, Ubuntu is faster there.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean you hardware is faulty. And Windows doesn't tamper with your Linux files, that's correct, I think. It's that when you hibernate an OS the OS relies on the platform and firmware to come back to the state were it hibernated, another OS can do something else and change that state. It's also not recommended to access filesystems that were actively mounted on the hibernated system, which usually results in data corruption. These are just a few points and as I said I'm not an engineer. **Edit:** Okay no problem. :)

Comment: Didn't know about the firmware part. Of course I'm careful to never mount windows ntfs partitions, that could be fatal. So I guess windows might actually be at fault here, tampering with stuff. Maybe that explains the 'ACPI more than one lid device found' error I get.

Comment: If Windows has a fast boot option, did you try disabling that?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps also, rather than dual booting, you could install a base hypervisor, and thus have multiple VMs able to enter and exit a suspended state without issue, as it is effectively the hypervisor dealing with each & thus just removing the problem entirely.